# Wifi Reception iPhone 6s Vs XR

Tags: iphone, wifi

I got a brand new iPhone XR and noticed that the it has quite poor wifi reception compared to iPhone 6s. On speed test I got 18.03mbps on 6s while only 4.92mbps on XR! Could this be due to thick XR body or should I get it checked. I noticed youtube videos take time to load on XR compared to 6s!

Is this normal or shall I get it checked out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the Wi-Fi antenna is kept close to the outer shell of the phone, so overall thickness shouldn't matter. This may be due to your wireless router being an older model and using an older standard than the XR was designed for (Wireless G/N, for example). Have you performed the speed test with both devices one after another, and have you attempted a test with a different Wi-Fi connection point to see if the problem is the router rather than the phone?

Comment: Yes my wireless router is Orbi Huwawei so its pretty new. I checked the speed at the same location and got the results as shown in the post. I think that somehow XR might not have a good wifi receiver to pick up signals if router is bit further away, iPhone 6s picks up quite fine. Also for perspective, my Mac gets full signal in the same location from the Wifi, maybe due to bigger antenna.